# export .po file into .csv

Tags: php, regex, csv, po

I am looking for a simple way to create an excel or CSV file from a .po localization file.

I couldn't find any via Google, so i'm thinking of writing it myself in PHP.
The PO file has such structure

msgid "Titre"
msgstr "Titre"

So i guess i need my PHP script to parse the .po file looking for "the first bit of text between comma after each occurrence of the keyword msgstr".

I assume that's the job for a regex, so i tried that, but it does not return anything:

```
$po_file = '/path/to/messages.po';

if(!is_file($po_file)){
    die("you got the filepath wrong dude.");
}

$str = file_get_contents($po_file);
// find all occurences of msgstr "SOMETHING"
preg_match('@^msgstr "([^/]+)"@i', $str, $matches);
$msgstr = $matches[1];

var_dump($msgstr);
```

Comment: Do you need to catch comment lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nice pear library. [File_Gettext](https://github.com/pear/File_Gettext)

If you look at the source [File/Gettext/PO.php](https://github.com/pear/File_Gettext/blob/master/File/Gettext/PO.php) you see the regex pattern that you'll need:

```
$matched = preg_match_all('/msgid\s+((?:".*(?<!\\\\)"\s*)+)\s+' .
                          'msgstr\s+((?:".*(?<!\\\\)"\s*)+)/',
                          $contents, $matches);

for ($i = 0; $i < $matched; $i++) {
    $msgid = substr(rtrim($matches[1][$i]), 1, -1);
    $msgstr = substr(rtrim($matches[2][$i]), 1, -1);

    $this->strings[parent::prepare($msgid)] = parent::prepare($msgstr);
}
```

Or just use the pear lib:

```
include 'File/Gettext/PO.php';

$po = new File_Gettext_PO();
$po->load($poFile);
$poArray = $po->toArray();

foreach ($poArray['strings'] as $msgid => $msgstr) {
    // write your csv as you like...
}
```

Comment: However, note that the pattern will fail with this string: `msgstr "abc\\\"def"`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte if you really found a bug you should write to [PEAR bug tracker](https://pear.php.net/bugs/report.php?package=File_Gettext&action=Report+Bug)

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake! It will fail with: `msgstr "abcdef\\"`

Comment: I couldn't make the PEAR solution work, but the first approach worked fine, with a bit of tweaking. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After search on Google and i've found this code to extract comment msgid, msgstr. It works!

```
$contents = file_get_contents("file.po");
$regex = '/^#\s*(.+?)\nmsgid "(.+?)"\nmsgstr "(.+?)"/m';
$matched = preg_match_all($regex, $contents, $matches );

$array = NULL;
for ($i = 0; $i < $matched; $i++) {
    $array[] = array('comment' => $matches[1][$i],
                     'msgid'   => $matches[2][$i],
                     'msgstr'  => $matches[3][$i]
                    );
}
print_r($array);
```